# How to create an exe file with MySQL database using Qt?

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5, qt6, qt6.4.1

I am doing a **qt** project with **MySQL** database. But I don't know how to create an **exe file with the MySQL database**. I want to know,

1. which extension I should use to export the database.
2. the way **how I should give the path to the database**.

please help me to solve this problem....

I tried some youtube tutorials and I was able to build an exe file but the database didn't work properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No one can possibly help debug the problem you are having without more information on what exactly you have done and what exactly is the problem. We have no access to your computer to get this information.